# This simple, single table query does a filesort, why?

Tags: mysql, optimization

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  KEY `status` (`status`,`type`,`created`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

the query

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE status = 1 AND type = 'discussion'
ORDER BY created DESC, title ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0\G
```

the result

```
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: test
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: status
          key: status
      key_len: 35
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1716
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY a  ASC, b  ASC` and
`ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC`
can avoid "filesort" (if they can use `INDEX(a,b)`).  But if you mix `ASC` and `DESC`, it cannot avoid a sort pass.

And, no, you cannot say `INDEX(a ASC, b DESC)`.  Or rather, you can *say* it, but `DESC` is *ignored* in the index definition.

Note that "filesort" may or may not actually touch disk.  In many cases, the sort can be done entirely in RAM.  What you are probably concerned about is the need to scan the entire table when you want only the first 'page'.

(This seems to be a watered down case.  If you would like to present the real schema, there might be other tips.)

Suggestion:  Use `DESC` for both fields and hint to the user that the dates were really different when he sees two titles in `DESC` order.

Since you seem to be doing "pagination", see how to [*remember where you left off*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) as an optimization for subsequent pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to your sorting. Run explain without the desc sort.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why so? I answered the question; "This simple, single table query does a filesort, why?"

Comment: You are probably right, it does answer the question. I guess my issue with your response is that it does poor job of explaining why that particular sorting causes a filesort, but what you've posted does qualify as an answer to the question as asked nevertheless.